# Bypassing some traffic from IIS to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, iis

I have my webapp built with JAVA/JSP and I redirected the traffic from IIS to Tomcat and it works fine. Is there anyway to tell IIS not to bypass traffic to specific folders to tomcat?

For example, let's see I have a website called Test and under it there is a folder called logon.. (Test/Logon). is there away to tell IIS not to pass the traffic to Tomcat when it comes to "Logon" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application Request Routing (ARR) with proper configuration (url mapping using wildcards or RE) would achieve what I requested.